# How to provide an .exe file as download on Windows Azure Website?

Tags: azure, clickonce

I am trying to publish a ClickOnce installer onto a website which is hosted on Windows Azure. The publishing process works as expected, nontheless the setup file is not available for download via HTTP. Obviously it is not possible to provide executables (*.exe) and libraries (*.dll) via HTTP. They are available via FTP, but HTTP requests yield a 'File not found' (404). After renaming the file to setup.txt, it can be downloaded, this doesn't really help, though. Can this be configured somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try by adding the following in your web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Client exe" path="*.exe" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Source: http://mike-ward.net/blog/post/00631/how-to-configure-iis-7-to-allow-downloading-exe-files.

Answer (score 1):

Add the allowed mime type to web config. Eg:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".exe" mimeType="application/exe"/>
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```